# Android, preview of minimized app in task switcher

Tags: android

I have a  requirement for our application to show stub image instead of real screen shot of application when it is minimized.

[image]

Lets imagine that i have to **show kitty instead of folders in Drop box application**. iOS has this possibility and seems android doesn't have.

Does anybody have some ideas?

Comment: the question doesn't relate to iOS. And Android does have this possibility.